# SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: la consulta no tiene un destino para los datos de resultado

Tags: postgresql

Tengo está función que cuando hay una excepción llama a otra función que sería guardar_excepciones_funciones.

```
    FOR i IN 0..1 LOOP
        IF id_pgdria[i] = 0 THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION '0';
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

RETURN id_pgdria;

EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
    parametros[1] := id_pgdria;
    parametros[2] := fchaoprcion;
    SELECT guardar_excepciones_funciones('cargue_listado_pagos', parametros, SQLERRM);
    RETURN parametros[2];
```

Pero al ejecutarse la función guardar_excepciones_funciones me genera el siguiente error:

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: la consulta no tiene un destino para los datos de resultado
```

Esté es el código de la función guardar_excepciones_funciones:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.guardar_excepciones_funciones(nombre_funcion_param text, valores_parametros text[], excepcion text)
 RETURNS character varying
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$DECLARE

msg varchar(100);
tipos_dato integer[];
nombre_tipo_dato text;
nombre_parametro text[];
valores_parametros_i text[] := valores_parametros;
id_funcion integer;
cantidad_tipos_dato integer;

BEGIN
    SELECT proc.proargtypes, proc.proargnames INTO tipos_dato, nombre_parametro 
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace namespace
        JOIN pg_catalog.pg_proc proc ON pronamespace = namespace.oid
        WHERE proc.proname = nombre_funcion_param;

    INSERT INTO log_funciones (nombre_funcion, respuesta_funcion, usuario_generador) 
        VALUES (nombre_funcion_param, excepcion, current_user);

    cantidad_tipos_dato := array_length(tipos_dato, 1); 
    SELECT id INTO id_funcion FROM log_funciones WHERE nombre_funcion = nombre_funcion_param;

    FOR i IN 0..cantidad_tipos_dato - 1 LOOP
        SELECT typname INTO nombre_tipo_dato FROM pg_catalog.pg_type WHERE oid = tipos_dato[i];
        INSERT INTO parametros_funcion_ejecucion (id_log_funciones, tipo_dato, nombre_parametro, valor_parametro)
            VALUES (id_funcion, nombre_tipo_dato, nombre_parametro[i + 1], valores_parametros_i[i + 1]);
    END LOOP;


    RETURN 'Se realizó la inserción de la expción';
END;$function$
;
```

He buscado en interne y aparece que es un error de un select, pero lo que yo hago es guardar los valores que vienen como parémetros.

Answer (score 1):

debes llamar a la función con  la clausula `PERFORM` si no te interesa lo que retorna la función que estas llamando:

```
    FOR i IN 0..1 LOOP
        IF id_pgdria[i] = 0 THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION '0';
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

RETURN id_pgdria;

EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
    parametros[1] := id_pgdria;
    parametros[2] := fchaoprcion;
    PERFORM guardar_excepciones_funciones('cargue_listado_pagos', parametros, SQLERRM);
    RETURN parametros[2];
```